# Displaying delimited data in Java console

Tags: java, string.format

So I'm trying to display CSV data (delimited) read by a file reader onto the console using String.format to keep the display clean.
Here is the sample data

Color, Number, ***Letter***
***Red***,    1002,    X
Blue,   1769,    Y
Greed,  1769,    Z

Whereas the code I use is as follows

```
try {

                fr = new FileReader(filepath);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);
                scan.useDelimiter(",");
                while(scan.hasNext()) {
                    String t = scan.next();
                    t = String.format("%10s", t);
                    System.out.print(t);
```

What I observed was that the last string of preceding line and first string of current line (made bold and italic in sample data) are combined into one string due to the delimiter. 
This happens for every line and messes up the display. I'm struggling to find a way around using only *string.format* method. Is this a limitation that I have to accept?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use "\n" also? May be  scan.useDelimiter(",\n");

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `Scanner` is how you should read the data from the csv file. Instead, use a more up-to-date way, that is `java.nio`.

I assume your `filepath` is a `String`, then you can read each line separately into a `List<String>` using this line of code (you may have to adjust the `StandardCharsets` value):

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filepath), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

In case you just want to display the data with `System.out`, you can do it like this,

> it will work well for small files (loads all the file content into the RAM)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // THIS HAS TO BE ADJUSTED TO YOUR PATH, OF COURSE
    String filePathString = "P:\\ath\\to\\your\\file.csv";

    Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);

    List<String> csvLines = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // This reads all the lines of the file into the List<String>
        csvLines = Files.readAllLines(filePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException while reading the csv file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (csvLines.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(csvLines.size() + " lines read, here they are:\n");

        csvLines.forEach(csvLine -> {
            System.out.println(csvLine);
        });

    } else {
        System.err.println("No lines read...");
    }
}
```

> For big files, you should be using a `Stream` (does not load everything into the RAM)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // THIS HAS TO BE ADJUSTED TO YOUR PATH, OF COURSE
    String filePathString = "P:\\ath\\to\\your\\file.csv";

    Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);

    List<String> csvLines = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // This is the only difference: streaming the file content line by line
        Files.lines(filePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).forEach(line -> {
            csvLines.add(line);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException while reading the csv file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (csvLines.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(csvLines.size() + " lines read, here they are:\n");

        csvLines.forEach(csvLine -> {
            System.out.println(csvLine);
        });

    } else {
        System.err.println("No lines read...");
    }

}
```

> **You don't have to use `String.format(...)` at all**